# Can I set an attribute based on the value of another attribute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have right now, and it does not work:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").attr('onclick', 'return goog_report_conversion(' + this.attr('href') + ')');
  });
});
</script>
```

Am I using the 'this' keyword incorrectly?

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use actual event handlers.

Comment: No, the line of code is not interpreted yet. So `this` will not refer to the `a` being clicked. (If that was what you wanted it to refer too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not going to assign the `onclick` inline in the element, I see no reason why you wouldn't just use a standard event handler. You can read more about the benefits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick).

I'd suggest this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    return goog_report_conversion(href);
});
```

**Also,** your first two lines of code are performing the same task, so you won't need both. ([More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454631/jquery-newbie-what-does-jqueryfunction-means/6454701))

```
jQuery(function($){ ... });

//  OR

$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

---

If you're wondering why yours doesn't work:

`attr()` doesn't have its own `this` arguments.

*(Tracing it upwards, the context in which you're using it would actually refer to the `document`, as the scope is defined by `$(document).ready( ... )` )*

If you *were* to do it that way, you'd likely need to modify your `goog_report_conversion()` function to accept a parameter of the clicked element, rather than the `href`. Your `this` would be included in the string, not concatenated. Using the passed element, you'd fetch the `href` similarly to how we did in the example above.

```
function goog_report_conversion(clicked_element) {
    var href = $(clicked_element).attr("href");
    //do something with href
});

$("a").attr("onclick", "return goog_report_conversion(this);");
```

That being said, **please don't do this.**

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! I learned a lot from your explanations and from the links you included.

Comment: What if it's not bound to any event. Just change it on load? I just need to override some styles imposed from some other js code.